# Detect when a programmatically opened tab is closed by the user

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm making a webapp with Angular 11 that uses the msgraph API to upload files to onedrive/sharepoint and then open the file in the Office online editor. This part is simple enough. I Also need to get the file back when the user is done with it. The requirement is that when the user closes the editor-tab I need to be notified of it, so I can download the file and delete it from onedrive/sharepoint.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-page',
  templateUrl: './test-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-page.component.scss']
})

export class TestPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  winGoogle!: Window | null;
  interval!: NodeJS.Timeout;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.detectClose, 1000);
  }

  openWin () {
    this.winGoogle = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
  }

  closeWin () {
    if(this.winGoogle) {
      this.winGoogle.close();
    }
  }

  detectClose() {
    //detect if the tab is closed by the user ( not from code ) and remove the interval

    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }
}
```

I tried to look at the value of the "handler" (this.winGoogle), but its undefined at all times.

Does anyone know how can I achieve it or is it at all possible?

Comment: `so I can download the file and delete it from onedrive/sharepoint.` ??? You are going to do it by hand?  You should create and use a server instead! Very probably doable by api in a secure way, and automaticity of course.

Comment: @NVRM The thing is, onedrive/sharepint will be used as a temporary fileshare to access the files. When not checked out the files will be stored in a seperate database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it can't be done without writing a browser extension.